# Design of a VHDL LUT Module

Tags: vhdl, lookup-tables

Description:
I am trying to write vhdl module a LUT (Look Up Table) with 4 inputs and 3 outputs. I want my 3 bit output to be a binary number equal to the number of 1's in the input.

My Truth Table:

> ABCD|XYZ
>   0000|000
>   0001|001
>   0010|001
>   0011|010
>   0100|011
>   0101|010
>   0110|010
>   0111|011
>   1000|001
>   1001|010
>   1010|010
>   1011|011
>   1100|010
>   1101|011
>   1110|011
>   1111|100

My VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity lut is
Port (
a : in STD_LOGIC; 
b : in STD_LOGIC; 
c : in STD_LOGIC; 
d : in STD_LOGIC; 
x : out STD_LOGIC; 
y : out STD_LOGIC; 
z : out STD_LOGIC);  

end lut;   

architecture Behavioral of lut is  
signal s0: STD_LOGIC;
signal s1: STD_LOGIC;
signal s2: STD_LOGIC;  
signal s3: STD_LOGIC;
signal s4: STD_LOGIC;
signal s5: STD_LOGIC;
signal s6: STD_LOGIC;
signal s7: STD_LOGIC; 
signal s8: STD_LOGIC;
signal s9: STD_LOGIC;
signal s10: STD_LOGIC;
signal s11: STD_LOGIC;
signal s12: STD_LOGIC;
signal s13: STD_LOGIC;

begin 
----------MUX1----------- 
process(a,b) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s0<=a;
else
s0<=b;
end if; 
end process; 

--------MUX2---------- 
process(a,b) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s1<=a;
else
s1<=b; 
end if;
end process;

---------MUX3-----------
process(a,b) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s2<=a;
else
s2<=b;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX4-----------
process(a,b) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s3<=a;
else
s3<=b;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX5-----------
process(c,d,a) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s4<=c;
else
s4<=d;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX6-----------
process(c,d,a) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s5<=c;
else
s5<=d;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX7-----------
process(c,d,a) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s6<=c;
else
s6<=d;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX8-----------
process(c,d,a) 
begin
if a='0' 
then s7<=c;
else
s7<=d;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX9-----------
process(s0,s1,b) 
begin
if b='0' 
then s8<=s0;
else
s8<=s1;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX10-----------
process(s2,s3,b) 
begin
if b='0' 
then s9<=s2;
else
s9<=s3;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX11-----------
process(s4,s5,b) 
begin
if b='0' 
then s10<=s4;
else
s10<=s5;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX12-----------
process(s6,s7,b) 
begin
if b='0' 
then s11<=s6;
else
s11<=s7;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX13-----------
process(s8,s9,c) 
begin
if c='0' 
then s12<=s8;
x<= s8;
else
s12<=s9;
x<= s9;
end if; 
end process;
---------MUX14-----------
process(s10,s11,c) 
begin
if c='0' 
then s13<=s10;
z<=s10;
else
s13<=s11; 
z<=s11
end if; 
end process; 
---------MUX15-----------
process(s12,s13,d) 
begin
if d='0' 
then y<=s12;
else
y<=s13;
end if; 
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Assumptions:
I need a total of 15 multiplexers to model what I need. They will be cascaded to one output.
I would have a total of 15 processes shown above.

Questions:
1.) What are my selects for the mux, ABCD?
2.) Am I modeling this the correct way? Will I achieve what I want from the info given?
3.) If there is a better way or you have a different Idea could you please provide an example?
4.) I am not getting my xyz output, its close but what am i doing wrong?

I have tried to provide as much research as possible. If you have any questions I will respond immediately

Comment: Your truth table has ABCD and XYZ. Why does your VHDL code not have X, Y, or Z, and instead has S1, F, G, and H? Also, why do you think you need to use any `inout` ports in a LUT implementation?

Comment: Your right i had not changed that since I was playing with selects. Anyway i changed it now. I don't need inout ports. So is what I am trying to do going to work or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and tell you to let your synthesizer optimize it.  Other than that you can use a minimizer (e.g. espresso) on your table then code the result in VHDL.

I'm guessing this should be what you should do when targeting an FPGA:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bit_count is
    port (
        a,b,c,d:   in  std_logic;
        x,y,z:     out std_logic    
    );
end entity;

architecture lut of bit_count is
    subtype lutin is std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    subtype lutout is std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    type lut is array (natural range 0 to 15) of lutout;
    constant bitcount:   lut := (
        "000", "001", "001", "010", 
        "011", "010", "010", "011", 
        "001", "010", "010", "011",
        "010", "011", "011", "100"
        );

    signal temp:    std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);

begin

    temp <= bitcount( TO_INTEGER ( unsigned (lutin'(a&b&c&d) ) ) );

    (x, y, z) <= lutout'(temp(2), temp(1), temp(0));

end architecture;
```

And failing that I think hand optimizing it as a ROM is likely to be close in terms of gate count:

```
--  0000   0001   0010   0011
--  "000", "001", "001", "010", 
--  0100   0101   0110   0111
--  "011", "010", "010", "011", 
--  1000   1001   1010   1011
--  "001", "010", "010", "011",
--  1100   1101   1110   1111
--  "010", "011", "011", "100"

-- output         Input
-----------------------
-- bit 0  is true 0001 0010 0100 0111 1000 1011 1101 1111
-- bit 1          0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110
-- bit 2          1111

architecture rom of bit_count is

    signal t0,t1,t2:    std_logic;
    signal t4,t7,t8:    std_logic;
    signal t11,t13,t14: std_logic;
    signal t15:         std_logic;

begin
-- terms
    t0  <= not a and not b and not c and not d;
    t1  <=     a and not b and not c and not d;
    t2  <= not a and     b and not c and not d;
--  t3  <=     a and     b and not c and not d;
    t4  <= not a and not b and     c and not d;
--  t5  <=     a and not b and     c and not d;
--  t6  <= not a and     b and     c and not d;
    t7  <=     a and     b and     c and not d;
    t8  <= not a and not b and not c and     d;
--  t9  <=     a and not b and not c and     d;
--  t10 <= not a and     b and not c and     d;
    t11 <=     a and     b and not c and     d;
--  t12 <= not a and not b and     c and     d;
    t13 <=     a and not b and     c and     d;
    t14 <= not a and     b and     c and     d;
    t15 <=     a and     b and     c and     d;

-- outputs

    x <= t15;

    y <= not ( t0 or t1 or t2 or t8 or t15 );

    Z <= t1 or t2 or t4 or t7 or t8 or t11 or t13 or t14;

end architecture;
```

It should be fewer gates than your chained multiplexers and a bit flatter (faster).

The two architectures have been analyzed but not simulated.  It's easy to get errors when doing hand gate level coding.

Comment: I like the above code, im not sure i follow all of it. I will look at it more to reveal what is happening. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are just fooling around in VHDL for fun or learning, if you want a LUT, write it directly as a LUT. There is probably no reason to unwrap this into low-level gates and muxes. Instead, simply describe the behavior you want, and let VHDL do the work for you:

For example, here is simple VHDL for the combinational logic LUT you've described:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Number_of_Ones is
    port (
        --- mapped 3=a, 2=b, 1=c, 0=d
        abcd : in std_ulogic_vector(3 downto 0);
        -- mapped x=2, y=1, z=0
        xyz  : out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
    );
end entity;

architecture any of Number_of_Ones is
begin

    process (abcd) is
    begin
        case abcd is      
        --abcd|xyz
        when "0000" => xyz <= "000";
        when "0001" => xyz <= "001";
        when "0010" => xyz <= "001";
        when "0011" => xyz <= "010";
        when "0100" => xyz <= "011";
        when "0101" => xyz <= "010";
        when "0110" => xyz <= "010";
        when "0111" => xyz <= "011";
        when "1000" => xyz <= "001";
        when "1001" => xyz <= "010";
        when "1010" => xyz <= "010";
        when "1011" => xyz <= "011";
        when "1100" => xyz <= "010";
        when "1101" => xyz <= "011";
        when "1110" => xyz <= "011";
        when "1111" => xyz <= "100";
        end case;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

As you can see, this is exactly your truth table copied in and just modified to fit VHDL syntax. You can of course write this in several different ways and you might wish to map ports differently, etc, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: I very much like your example above. I am just learning vhdl and I assumed that I would have to unwrap this into lower level stuff but I see your point. thanks

Answer (score 4):

As another "trust the tools" answer, if you want to count the ones, just do that.  Your code will be clearer and the synthesizer will make a remarkably good job of it:

```
process(clk)
  variable count : unsigned(xyz'range)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
     count := (others => '0');
     for i in abcd'range loop
        if abcd(i) = '1' then
           count := count + 1;
        end if;
     end loop;
     xyz <= count;
   end if;
end process;
```

I haven't compiled or simulated this, but it should give you the idea...  Of course, for full code-clarity, you'd encapsulate the `count`/`loop` aspect in a function called `count_ones` and call that from the process.

Comment: +1 clear and concise. Unless you find that the tools are horribly synthesizing your design, a functional/behavioral approach is almost always easier to maintain.

Comment: Another reason to use this direct algorithmic style is this entry in the original post's truth table: `0100|011`. Nobody appeared to notice that bug for more than 2 years!